# Creating simple x y grid with no projection for non geographical spatial analysis in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I want to analyse a part of the body for which I have high resolution images that have Non-geographical coordinates on an x y grid.

How can I create this as a project in qgis without creating crs based problems?

I guess I make my own but I'm not sure of the syntax to use.

Comment: If the CRS doesn't matter, just pick any one.

Comment: If you are working on such a small scale the CRS makes no difference whatsoever. There is no "no CRS" option. However you can manually create a 'flat surface' under --> extra --> custom CRS. I don't know the parameters for it but I am sure you can find that somewhere.